# O que significa .container.\31 25\25 em CSS?

Tags: css3

Estou fazendo um auto estudo em site responsivo. Num tutorial que eu obtive, há no arquivo CSS instruções como:

```
.container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1750px;
    min-width: 1400px;
}

.container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 1050px;
}

.container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 700px;
}

.container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 350px;
}
```

Qual o significado de:

```
.container.\31 25\25 
.container.\37 5\25
.container.\35 0\25
.container.\32 5\25
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [especificação do CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), são caracteres de escape, porque os identificadores do CSS não podem ter caracteres especiais, ou melhor, só podem ter caracteres a-Z e 1-9, caracteres ISO 10646, hífen e sublinhado (underline, underscore).

```
.container.\31 25\25 = .container.125%
.container.\37 5\25  = .container.75%
.container.\35 0\25  = .container.50%
.container.\32 5\25  = .container.25%
```